# How resolve an issue with dxgi.dll?

Tags: windows-7, boot, aero, dll

How resolve this issue with **dxgi.dll**? I originally thought issue was related to Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe). However, after trying run a System File Check, I got similar error related to **dxgi.dll**. I know the issue is related to this file. How do I fix this issue? I tried replacing the DLL file from one found online. However, *system32* folder locks up, in both normal start up and safe mode, when searching for dxgi.dll in the folder or scrolling down to it and clicking on it.

#### What I know or have already tried:

- Error in <strike>both Safe Mode &</strike> Normal Start Up upon login
- Restored to a 3-day old Restore Point
- Last install was iTunes 3 days before the issue begin
- No changes were made in the past week or longer
- Reinstalled DirectX
- No other graphic or display issues
- Ran Full Virus Scan via Norton Internet Security
- Uninstalled and Installed the latest GeForce 460M drivers
- Windows is completely updated
- Ran System File Check but failed at 11% (Normal & Safe Mode) - *See Screenshot*

#### Screenshots:

[image: Error: dwm.exe - Bad Image]
*Error when running System File Check.*

[image: Error: dwm.exe - Bad Image]
*Original error on start up.*

Comment: Does this happen if you boot in Safe Mode?

Comment: Try reinstalling/updating directx.

Comment: Yes it happens in Safe Mode too.

Comment: This isn't a virus. It's probably a driver issue, so it'll be interesting to hear what happens when you've updated the video driver.

Comment: Took longer than expected to update my question. Internet service in Afghanistan isn't the greatest. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Try seeing what [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) says about the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all the troubleshooting steps in my question, I decided to do a fresh install. A restore from a backup image would have worked too.